# Background service closes when the screen is blocked, only with Huawei

Tags: android, service, background, huawei-mobile-services

I had created an alarm, with a foreground service. It runs fine. It works well with all mobiles, but it does not work with Huawei, where this service, close when screen is locked. Does anyone have any ideas to fix it? Please help.

This is part of my code:

```
public class ServiceWakeUp extends Service {
    ServiceWakeUp activity;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    String fname = "cheerful_2", wakeups = "";
    AudioManager audio;
    Dialog dia;

    Thread runner2;
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            StartService();
        }
    };
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    int elapsed;
    //PowerManager pm;
    //PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        SelectClasses select = new SelectClasses(activity);
        wakeups = select.getCalendarsSaved("");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        activity = this;
        getInitialNotifForForeground();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        dia = new Dialog(activity);
        //mantenim la CPU encesa
        //pm = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
        // wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,getPackageName());
        // wl.acquire();

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);

        audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        for(int a = 0;a < 5;a++)
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

        SelectClasses select = new SelectClasses(activity);
        wakeups = select.getCalendarsSaved("");
        elapsed = preferences.getInt("runner",0);
    }
}
```

And here. You can see the BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class ReceiverBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SelectClasses select = new SelectClasses(context);

        if(select.existActivedWakeup()){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ServiceWakeUp.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceWakeUp.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com

Comment: Thanks, but developer solution only for EMUI 4??? My devices has EMUI 9+

Comment: I try it, but not work. Now, with powerManager, Service not stop when Thread.interrupt, or stop always some minutes after, on other devices. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to configure the app launch settings, try with this:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity")
try {
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    // Fallback to global settings
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look